# SSRS “Subquery returned more than 1 value”

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, subquery

I'm using MS Visual Studio 2012. I'm having an issue with writing a subquery. This is the entire query as follows:

```
SELECT ACCOUNTNUM
    , NAME
    , ADDRESS
    , PHONE
    , TELEFAX
    , INVOICEACCOUNT
    , CUSTGROUP
    , PAYMTERMID
    , CURRENCY
    , DIMENSION
    , CELLULARPHONE
    , STATISTICSGROUP
    , PAYMMODE
    , NAMEALIAS
    , CONTACTPERSONID
    , STREET
    , PARTYID
    , SEGMENTID
    , TAXGROUP
    , DATAAREAID
    , ISNULL((
            SELECT PERCENT1 AS DiscCount
            FROM PRICEDISCTABLE
            WHERE (DATAAREAID = CUSTTABLE.DATAAREAID)
                AND (ACCOUNTRELATION = CUSTTABLE.ACCOUNTNUM)
            ), 0) / 100 AS DiscCount
    , (
        SELECT NAME
        FROM CONTACTPERSON
        WHERE (DATAAREAID = CUSTTABLE.DATAAREAID)
            AND (CUSTACCOUNT = CUSTTABLE.ACCOUNTNUM)
            AND (CONTACTPERSONID = CUSTTABLE.CONTACTPERSONID)
        ) AS ContactName
    , (
        SELECT PHONE
        FROM CONTACTPERSON AS CONTACTPERSON_1
        WHERE (DATAAREAID = CUSTTABLE.DATAAREAID)
            AND (CUSTACCOUNT = CUSTTABLE.ACCOUNTNUM)
            AND (CONTACTPERSONID = CUSTTABLE.CONTACTPERSONID)
        ) AS ContactPhone
    , ISNULL((
            SELECT STATGROUPNAME
            FROM CUSTSTATISTICSGROUP
            WHERE (DATAAREAID = CUSTTABLE.DATAAREAID)
                AND (CUSTSTATISTICSGROUP = CUSTTABLE.STATISTICSGROUP)
            ), 0) AS StatisticsName
FROM CUSTTABLE
WHERE CUSTGROUP = @ty
    AND DATAAREAID = N'OTN'
    AND STATISTICSGROUP LIKE @ss;
```

and then I get the error

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression.

Comment: The error message says it all, you have at least on sub-select that returns more than 1 row. That's not allowed in the select list. Do JOINS instead.

Comment: You are seeking for debugging help which is off-topic on StackOverflow. As jarlh stated, the error message contains all information you need to solve the problem, furthermore searching for the error message will give you plenty of results.

Answer (score 2):

**Where the issue comes from?**

Issue is that one of your subqueries returns more than one value (HEY, ERROR DESCRIPTION SAYS THAT).

**How to find which one?**

Try commenting out each subquery in your select statement until your query works fine.

**How to fix it?**

That's probably the best case to use [CROSS APPLY](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). That'd be your query:

```
SELECT ACCOUNTNUM
    , NAME
    , ADDRESS
    , PHONE
    , TELEFAX
    , INVOICEACCOUNT
    , CUSTGROUP
    , PAYMTERMID
    , CURRENCY
    , DIMENSION
    , CELLULARPHONE
    , STATISTICSGROUP
    , PAYMMODE
    , NAMEALIAS
    , CONTACTPERSONID
    , STREET
    , PARTYID
    , SEGMENTID
    , TAXGROUP
    , DATAAREAID
    , ISNULL(T1.DiscCount, 0) / 100 AS DiscCount
    , T2.ContactName
    , T3.ContactPhone
    , ISNULL(T4, 0) AS StatisticsName
FROM CUSTTABLE
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT PERCENT1 AS DiscCount
    FROM PRICEDISCTABLE
    WHERE DATAAREAID = CUSTTABLE.DATAAREAID
        AND ACCOUNTRELATION = CUSTTABLE.ACCOUNTNUM
    ) AS T1
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT NAME
    FROM CONTACTPERSON
    WHERE DATAAREAID = CUSTTABLE.DATAAREAID
        AND CUSTACCOUNT = CUSTTABLE.ACCOUNTNUM
        AND CONTACTPERSONID = CUSTTABLE.CONTACTPERSONID
    ) AS T2
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT PHONE
    FROM CONTACTPERSON AS CONTACTPERSON_1
    WHERE DATAAREAID = CUSTTABLE.DATAAREAID
        AND CUSTACCOUNT = CUSTTABLE.ACCOUNTNUM
        AND CONTACTPERSONID = CUSTTABLE.CONTACTPERSONID
    ) AS T3
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT STATGROUPNAME
    FROM CUSTSTATISTICSGROUP
    WHERE DATAAREAID = CUSTTABLE.DATAAREAID
        AND CUSTSTATISTICSGROUP = CUSTTABLE.STATISTICSGROUP
    ) AS T4
WHERE CUSTGROUP = @ty
    AND DATAAREAID = N'OTN'
    AND STATISTICSGROUP LIKE @ss;
```

Also, these can be rewritten as simple INNER JOINS.

Comment: Good answer and well detailed

Answer (score 0):

When encountering this error, try running the subqueries individually and if more than one record is returned then refine your conditions to ensure only one record is returned.

Of course, if more than one record is wanted then you need to change your query to use a join instead of a subquery.

Comment: Or, if the subquery returns one column, use 'IN' instead of '='